# What should I do to be able to send signals to slots with QVector of my custom class objects

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

What should I do to be able to send signals to slots with `QVector` of my custom class objects as an argument?

```
struct LicenseInfo
{
    QString company_name;
    QString server_name;
    QString product_name;
    int product_version;
    QString license_end;
    QString last_update;
    QString comment;
};
```

Usage

```
connect(_worker, SIGNAL(newLicensesActivated(QVector<LicenseInfo>)),
                 this, SLOT(newLicensesActivated(QVector<LicenseInfo>)));
```

It is ok to do the following?

```
#include "licenseinfo.h"

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(LicenseInfo)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    qRegisterMetaType<QVector<LicenseInfo>>();

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Should I use both `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro and `qRegisterMetaType` function in this case?

Comment: What feedback are you getting?

Comment: @LogicStuff It seems that it works, but I'm not sure whether I have to do it this way

Comment: It might just work without any one of the options, have you tried that?
I think QVector is already registered, thus it should be able to handle any vector (just a guess)

Comment: @The Badger Yeah, I already tried it and got the following error -- "QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<LicenseInfo>'
(Make sure 'QVector<LicenseInfo>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)"

Comment: @FrozenHeart ah ok, then what you are doing seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing I would worry about when trying to pass Qt Containers of objects is to make sure that the objects in the containers don't go out of scope.  If the contents are trivial or simple types, this is not necessary.

I prefer to make the items on the heap (using `new`), and pass around containers of pointers.  Then I make sure I clean them up properly at the end of its lifecycle... often using [`qDeleteAll()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll-1).  It requires a little more planning up front, but it reduces a lot of bugs later.

Also I like making sure I am using the right [container](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html) for the job.  Like it might make sense to use a QSet instead of a QVector, or even just use a QList instead.  But then you may need to implement a comparison operator to make it so that the objects can be compared and sorted.

Another piece of advice, be careful about having `>>` in your qRegisterMetaType or in any declaration for that matter.  Add a space inbetween so it isn't ambiguous. `qRegisterMetaType< QVector<LicenseInfo>       >();` (note the exaggerated space).

Hope that helps.

Comment: "be careful about having >> in your qRegisterMetaType or in any declaration for that matter" -- what's the reason behind it? It's perfectly legal since C++03 or C++11

Comment: "The biggest thing I would worry about when trying to pass Qt Containers of objects is to make sure that the objects in the containers don't go out of scope" -- is it possible? I thought that it's guaranteed that the objects that I passed as an argument to the signal will be alive

Comment: Depending on the machine I am using, I don't always have the luxury of an up to date compiler, or a compiler that is fully compliant.  I was unaware that it had been fixed in more recent C++ revisions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1668276/999943  The copy-on-write idiom I think is the catch that has caused issues for me or for others I was helping debug their code with.

Comment: Copy on write has nothing to do with this. Objects that you put in a container are copied and owned by the container.

Comment: @FrozenHeart: yes, everything is OK.