# C++ read-only struct that can be set from within a class?

Tags: c++, performance, struct, qvector

I have a class `Foo` that has defined a public struct `Data` inside of it, with a `QVector<Data> allData` nesting multiple objects of the `Data` struct inside of it:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        struct Data {
            uchar valueA;
            uchar valueB;
            uchar valueC;
        };
    private:
        QVector<Data> allData;
};
```

I also have two other classes B and C that need to read `allData` multiple times a second. They shall not be able to write into `allData` at all, this shall be handled by the `Foo` class only.

With performance in mind, I'm looking for a way to do this without creating a new QVector everytime. As far as I understand, a method like this:

```
QVector<Data> getAllData() {
    return allData;
}
```

would result in a new object being created everytime this method gets called.

If I gave the other classes something like a `QVector<Data> allDataCopy` that is just being handed over to `Foo` to be filled with the values inside of `allData` that would just result in having to copy all values everytime, which I imagine would not be very perfomant aswell.

Is there any efficient way to solve this?

Comment: `QVector` is [cheap to copy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html). That said, you can make it `const QVector<Data>& getAllData()`

Comment: You could return by const reference, since the value is a member variable, but I am unsure if this is safe or not.

Comment: "multiple times a second": please give the order of "mutliple" we're talking. Units? Tens? Hundreds? Millions?

Comment: Why do you use QVector instead of std::vector?

Comment: @manni66: I was thinking that could be the basis for a question on its own. Turns out [there is one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1668259/10077).

Answer (score 4):

Your "getters" should not return by value unless you want to force a copy on the user. Provide two overloads that will respectively return an *lvalue reference* and a *`const` lvalue reference* (or only the `const` one if you don't want users of `Foo` to mutate `allData`):

```
QVector<Data>& getAllData() {
    return allData;
}

const QVector<Data>& getAllData() const {
    return allData;
}
```

This will still allow your user to make a copy (if wanted), but also enable your user to just observe/mutate `allData` through a reference, without any copy.

---

In C++11 and above, if `QVector` supports move semantics, you might want to overload on the `&&` ref qualifier as well:

```
QVector<Data>& getAllData()       &      { return allData; }
const QVector<Data>& getAllData() const& { return allData; }
QVector<Data> getAllData()        &&     { return std::move(allData); }
```

This allows users to conveniently move `allData` from an rvalue of type `Foo`.

Comment: Good advice in general. Though I would like to add t hat `QVector` are implicitly shared. The copy constructor is always constant time and, instead, the elements are copied  when any reference writes to a shared instance.

Comment: QVector [has a move constructor since Qt 5.2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#QVector-4). But having a getter that moves a member variable seems like an awful idea. Am I wrong?

Comment: @FredLarson Notice that particular getter is reference qualified with `&&` meaning it only participates if you are calling it from an rvalue. For example `std::move(foo).getAllData()` would move out `allData` but `foo.getAllData()` would not.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks. I'm not accustomed to those qualifiers yet.

Comment: The OP doesn't want the first overload, the second is sufficient.

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo, would that still work with allData being `private` as in question code?

Comment: @MohammadKanan: sure, why not.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, because in question, it will be called from two _**other**_ classes B, C.

Comment: If you let the caller get a non-const reference to a private member, why not simply let that member be public?

Comment: Made it call by reference, thank you very much. TIL!

Answer (score 3):

`QVector` is cheap to copy; it uses smart reference copy on write semantics.

If your code has any danger of multiple thread access, `QVector const&` is dangerous, as references are not thread safe.  The same kind of danger can occur if you are reentrant, and cause the `QVector` to be modified while someone else is holding onto the `QVector const&`.

Simply return a copy of `QVector`.  Fancy alternatives involving references can cause potential bugs, do not consider them until you have evidence that the small cost of "copying" a `QVector` is causing performance issues.